# Drag and Drop operation in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

Here i have a listview which is inflated with couple of textviews. It consists of a list of tasks that i wish to do and it has a priority field as 1,2,3 so on in the the tasks object. The list is populated in the order based on the priority, How can i drag a task and drop it which would occupy that priority in listview. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look on the following link to dowload source code

[How to implement Drag and Drop functionality on ListView.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist)

Also you can see following link

http://good-good-study.appspot.com/blog/posts/132001

Answer (score 0):

I also have a recent implementation at:

- https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

Looks like you have some choices.